# Config file with cobra and viper

Tags: go, viper-go, go-cobra

**Basic information:** I have created a go application and used Cobra for it. Cobra uses Viper for command line parameters and flags.

I have a command listen with a flag bind and I want to configure it in a yaml file.

**Code:**

The init function of the listen command looks like this:

```
func init() {
    RootCmd.AddCommand(listenCmd)
    listenCmd.Flags().StringP("bind", "b", ":50051", "Provide bind definition")
    viper.BindPFlag("bind", listenCmd.Flags().Lookup("bind"))
}
```

Code of my application is at https://github.com/sascha-andres/go-logsink

**Problem:**

When I call the app with `listen --bind "bla"` the flag is set correctly to `bla`, but I have not found a way to achieve this using a YAML file located in my home directory.

**Config files tried:**

```
---

connect:
  bind: "bla"
```

and

```
---

bind: "bla"
```

In both cases the config file was found but the flag had not the expected value but the default value.

How do I have to write the config file to have the flag populated correctly?

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to reproduce your problem: I tried with my yaml config file in /tmp and your code, and the bind param was correctly found and set to its config value. However, I noticed that the bind param must not be nested to be found, is that the case in your config ?

Comment: @T.Claverie I have currently the second version ( not nested ). I have pasted it at http://pastebin.com/7TcqrdgV. Updated question with link to the complete source

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why is cobra not reading my config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43847791/why-is-cobra-not-reading-my-config-file)

Comment: @WGH for your reference: this is 1 year 5 months old, the other one 1 year 2 months, no need to vote for close here

Comment: @Sascha I know, but the other question is slightly more understandable, as it includes the problematic part - using variable bound to pflag instead of `viper.GetString()` - and this question only has a link to repository which no longer has the code in question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, thanks for the additional information, It helped a lot !

### Problem

The problem arises from the way you're retrieving the value of the flag. Here is what you currently have:

```
bind := cmd.Flag("bind").Value.String()
fmt.Printf("Binding definition provided: %s\n", bind)
server.Listen(bind)
```

When binding a flag with viper, it's actually viper that will hold the final value, according to this priorities:

```
1. If present, use the flag value
2. Else, use the value from the config file
3. Else, use the default flag value
```

Your problem is that you retrieve the flag value from the flag set of the command, and not from viper.

### Behavior

Here is the code I tested:

```
bind := cmd.Flag("bind").Value.String()
fmt.Printf("Binding definition provided: %s\n", bind)
fmt.Printf("Binding definition provided from viper: %s\n", viper.GetString("bind"))
```

Without the bind config param:

```
$ go-logsink listen
Using config file: /xxx/.go-logsink.yaml
Binding definition provided: :50051
Binding definition provided from viper: :50051
```

With the bind config param set to "bla" (not nested, second config file):

```
$ go-logsink listen
Using config file: /xxx/.go-logsink.yaml
Binding definition provided: :50051
Binding definition provided from viper: bla
```

With the bind config param set to "bla" (not nested, second config file) and an explicit flag:

```
$ go-logsink listen --bind ":3333"
Using config file: /xxx/.go-logsink.yaml
Binding definition provided: :3333
Binding definition provided from viper: :3333
```

**Bottomline** : when binding your flags with viper, use viper to retrieve them.

**Additional note** : In your README, the proper way to generate grpc compatible code is by adding the grpc plugin to protobuf generation: `protoc --go_out=plugins=grpc:. *.proto`